# When I click on the button the hidden content doesn't show, why is this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying create a read more read less button. My content that is hidden is in a span tag. I used some javascript to make this work. Currently, when I click on the button nothing happens. My goal is to create a news section that shows more news when you click on the button.

This was working for me before, I used the exact same code and just merged it with some other code and it stopped working.

```js
     $(document).ready(function () {


 var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

 var navOpen = false;
 var onCloseBtn = false;
 var onAccordian = false;

 $("#hamburger").mouseover(function(){
  if(!navOpen){
   openMenu(); 
  }
  onCloseBtn = true;
 });

 $("#hamburger").mouseout(function(){
  onCloseBtn = false;
 });

 $("#hamburger").click(function(){
  toggleNav();
  console.log("clickedHam");
 });

 $("#navMenu").mouseover(function(){
  if(!navOpen && !onCloseBtn){
   keepOpen(); 
  }
 });
 

 $("#activeSpace").mouseleave(function(){
   console.log("navMenu Mouseout");
   closeMenu();
 });

 function toggleNav(){
  if(navOpen){
   closeMenu();
   
  } else {
   openMenu();
  }
 }
 function keepOpen(){
  console.log("keepOpen");
  navOpen = true;
  $('#hamburger').html('&times;');
  $('#hamburger').css("color","black");
  $("#navMenu").css("visibility","visible");
  $("#navMenu").css("height","auto");
  $("#navMenu").css("max-height", windowHeight); 
 }

 function openMenu(){
  console.log("open");
  navOpen = true;
  $('#hamburger').html('&times;');
  $('#hamburger').css("color","black");
  $("#navMenu").css("visibility","visible");
  $("#navMenu").css("max-height", "250px"); ///change this depending on the max
 }

 function closeMenu(){
  closePanels();
  navOpen = false;
  console.log("close")
  $('#hamburger').html('&#9776;');
  $('#hamburger').css("color","white");
  $("#navMenu").css("max-height", "0");
  $("#navMenu").css("visibility","hidden");
 }


 $(document).on('scroll', function() {
  if($(this).scrollTop()>=$('#changeNavColor').position().top - 40 && !navOpen){
   $(hamburger).css("color","black");
  }
  if($(this).scrollTop()<$('#changeNavColor').position().top - 40 && !navOpen){
   $(hamburger).css("color","white");
  }
 });



 var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-accordian");
 var i;

 for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
   //this.classList.toggle("active");
   $("#navMenu").css("height","auto");
   $("#navMenu").css("max-height", windowHeight); 
   
   var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
   if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
   } else {
     panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
   }
  });
 }


 function closePanels() {
  var panels = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-accordian-panel");
  var j;

  for (j = 0; j < panels.length; j++){
   panels[j].style.maxHeight = null;
  }
 }

function toggleNewsButton() {
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (!moreText.style.display || moreText.style.display === "none") {
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    moreText.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  }
}

});
```

```css
     html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 }

 h1{
  font-size: 3em;
 }
 h2{
  font-size: 1.5em;
 }

 h3{
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight:400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }



 .FullsizeImg{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30%;
  background-position: right;

 }
 #more {
   display: none;
 }

 #myBtn {
   color: black;
   background: #fff;
   border: 1px solid black;
   font-size: 17px;
   padding: 7px 12px;
   font-weight: normal;
   margin: 6px 0;
   margin-right: 12px;
 }

 .centerButton {
   text-align: center;
 }

 #myBtn:hover,
 #myBtn:active {
   background: black;
   color: white;
 }

 .allStories{
  margin-left:20px;
  margin-right:20px;
 }


 #hamburger{
  z-index: 11;
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.25 ease;
 }

 #closeBtn{
  display:block;
  position:fixed;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
 }

 #navMenu{
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
  overflow:hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(33,33,33,.6);
  max-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: 1s ease;
  -o-transition: 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: 1s ease;
  transition: 1s ease;
  visibility: hidden;
 }



 .nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

 .nav ul li {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: regular;
  font-family: inherit;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease;
 }

 .nav li:hover {
  color: lightgrey;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease;
 }

 .mainMargins{
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
 }

 .smallSpacer{
  height: 25px;
 }

 .bigSpacer{
  height: 100px;
 }

 .txtAlignRight{

 }

 .AlwaysFullScreen{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }

 .fullScreen{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }

 .withBGImg{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
 }

 .jumbo-title{
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
 }

 .jumbo-caption{
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 
 }


 .jumbo-container{
  color: white;
 }

 .verticalCentreParent{
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
 }

 .verticalCentreChild{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
 }

 .content-verticalCentreParent{
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
 }

 .content-verticalCentreChild{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
 }

 .iconContainer{
  text-align: center;
 }
 .mediumIcons{
  height: 100px;
 }

 .scrollCard{
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(33,33,33,.2);
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: .3s ease;
  -o-transition: .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: .3s ease;
  transition: .3s ease;
 }

 .scrollCard:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 0 11px rgba(33,33,33,.5);
 }

 .scrollCardBar {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  margin: 0;
 }

 .scrollCard {
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 8px;
 }
 .scrollCardContainer{
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
 }

 .scrollCardBar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
 }

 .endOfScroll{
  width: 100px;
 }

 .line{
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 1px;
 }

 footer{
  height: auto;
  background-color: #5388EF;
  color: white;
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
 }



 footer ul{
  font-weight: 300;
  list-style-type: none;

  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0;
 }

 footer li{
  padding: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
 }

 footer .row{
  margin: auto;
 }

 footer .footer-column{
  width: calc(100% / 6);
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
 }

 @media only screen and (min-width: 2000px){
  .mainMargins{
   margin-left: 25%;
   margin-right: 25%;
  }
  .scrollCardContainer{
   margin-left: 25%;
   margin-right: 25%;
  }
 }

 @media only screen and (max-height: 1000px){
  .fullScreen{
   height: auto;
   width: auto;
  }

  .content-verticalCentreChild{
   position: relative;
   top: 100%;
   transform: none;
  }
 }


 @media only screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
  footer .footer-column{
   width: calc(100% / 3);
  }
 }


 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  h1{
   font-size: 2em;
  }

  h2{
   font-size: 1em;
  }

  
  #hamburger{
   top: 5px;
  left: px;
  }
  
  .mobile-accordian-panel{
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: .3s ease;
  -o-transition: .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: .3s ease;
  transition: .3s ease;

  } 
  

  .mainMargins{
   margin-left: 8%;
   margin-right: 8%;
  }

  .content-verticalCentreChild{
   position: relative;
   top: 100%;
   transform: none;
  }
  .scrollCardContainer{
   margin-left: 8%;
   margin-right: 8%;
  }
  .endOfScroll{
   width: 16px;
  }
  footer .footer-column{
   width: 100%
  }

 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/main.js"></script>


  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

 </head>

<body>

 <div class = "nav">
   <span id="hamburger" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer">&#9776;    </span>
   <div id = "activeSpace">
  <div id = "navMenu">
    <div class = "row mainMargins" style="margin-top:20px;">
      <div class = "col-sm-3">
        <div class = "mobile-accordian">
          <h3>Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class = "mobile-accordian-panel">
          <ul class = "menu-subItems">
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Mission</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Social</li>
            <li>Get in touch</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class = "col-sm-3">
        <div class = "mobile-accordian">
          <h3>Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class = "mobile-accordian-panel">
          <ul class = "menu-subItems">
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Mission</li>
          </ul>
        </div></div> 
        <div class = "col-sm-3"><div class = "mobile-accordian">
          <h3>Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class = "mobile-accordian-panel">
          <ul class = "menu-subItems">
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Mission</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Social</li>
          </ul>
        </div></div>
        <div class = "col-sm-3"><div class = "mobile-accordian">
          <h3>Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class = "mobile-accordian-panel">
          <ul class = "menu-subItems">
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Mission</li>
            <li>Services</li>
          </ul>
        </div> 
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "smallSpacer"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>


<section id = "landing" class = "AlwaysFullScreen">
  <div class = "AlwaysFullScreen withBGImg verticalCentreParent" style = "background-image: url(/images/placeHolder.jpg)">
    <div class = "jumbo-container verticalCentreChild mainMargins">
      <img class = "logo" src = "/images/logo.png">
      <div class = "smallSpacer"></div>
      <h1 class = "jumbo-title">Catchy Headline That Spans Multiple Lines</h1>
      <h2 class = "jumbo-caption">Headline Caption (Optional)</h2>
    </div>
    </div>
   </section>

<div id="changeNavColor"></div>

   <section id = "#" class="fullScreen">
     <div class = "fullScreen content-verticalCentreParent">
    <div class = "mainMargins content-verticalCentreChild">
      <div class = "row">
        <div class = "iconContainer col-sm-4 content-verticalCentreParent" style="">
          <img class = "mediumIcons verticalCentreChild" src = "/images/placeHolder.jpg" >
        </div>
        <div class = "col-sm-8">
          <h1>Title</h1>
          <p>This is paragraph text. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document without relying on meaningful content (also called greeking). This is paragraph text. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document without relying on meaningful content (also called greeking). </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "bigSpacer"></div>
      <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-sm-8 text-right">
          <h1>Title</h1>
          <p>This is paragraph text. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document without relying on meaningful content (also called greeking). This is paragraph text. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document without relying on meaningful content (also called greeking).</p>
        </div>
        <div class = "iconContainer col-sm-4 verticalCentreParent">
          <img class = "mediumIcons verticalCentreChild" src = "/images/placeHolder.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "bigSpacer"></div>
      <div class = "row">
        <div class = "iconContainer col-sm-4 verticalCentreParent" style="">
          <img class = "mediumIcons verticalCentreChild" src = "/images/placeHolder.jpg" >
        </div>
        <div class = "col-sm-8">
          <h1>Title</h1>
          <p>This is paragraph text. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document without relying on meaningful content (also called greeking). This is paragraph text. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document without relying on meaningful content (also called greeking). </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    </div>
  </section>


  <section id = "#" class="fullScreen">
    <div class = "fullScreen content-verticalCentreParent">
      <div class = "content-verticalCentreChild">
       <div class = "mainMargins">
     <h1>Title</h1>
     <p>This is paragraph text. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document without relying on meaningful content (also called greeking). This is paragraph text. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document without relying on meaningful content (also called greeking).</p>
   </div>
   <div class = "bigSpacer"></div>

   <div class="scrollCardBar">
    <div class = "scrollCardContainer">
      <div class="scrollCard"></div>
      <div class="scrollCard"></div>
      <div class="scrollCard"></div>
      <div class="scrollCard"></div>
      <div class="scrollCard"></div>
      <div class="scrollCard"></div>
      <div class="scrollCard"></div>
      <div class="scrollCard"></div>
      <div class="scrollCard"></div>
      <div class="scrollCard"></div>
      <div class = "endOfScroll"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="#" class="fullScreen">
  <div class = "fullScreen content-verticalCentreParent FullsizeImg" style ="background-image: url(/images/brain.svg)">
    <div class = "content-verticalCentreChild">
     <div class = "mainMargins">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>This is paragraph text. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document without relying on meaningful content (also called greeking). This is paragraph text. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document without relying on meaningful content (also called greeking). </p> 
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </section>


<section id="#" class="">
  <div class = "mainMargins">
    <h1 id ="#" style = "text-align:center;" > Meet Our Reseachers</h1>
    <h3>This is paragraph text. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document without relying on meaningful content (also called greeking).    </h3>

    <div class ="row">
      <div class = "col-sm-4" style ="text-align: center;">
        <img class="imagePeople" src = "/images/person1.jpg" style = "height: 300px;">
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <small>A groundbreaking blueprint for store-program computers. Though a complete version of the ACE was never built, its concept has been used as a model by tech corporations worldwide for several years</small>
      </div>

      <div class = "col-sm-4" style ="text-align: center;">
        <img class="imagePeople" src = "/images/person2.jpg" style = "height: 300px;">
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <small>He first addressed the issue of artificial intelligence in his 1950 paper, "Computing machinery and intelligence". If an AI can convice a human that is it human, it should be considered intelligent.</small>
      </div>

      <div class = "col-sm-4" style ="text-align: center;">
        <img class="imagePeople" src = "/images/person3.jpg" style = "height: 300px;">
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <small>The highest acheivable award in the field of computer science. Named after Alan Turing for his grand contributions and is equivalent to the Noble Prize.</small><div class="bigSpacer"></div><div class="bigSpacer"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   
  <div class="bigSpacer"></div>

</section>


<section id="#" class="">

  
  <div class = "mainMargins">
    <h1 id ="#" style = "text-align:center;" > News</h1>
    <h3 id ="#" style = "text-align:center;" > Read the Storie’s of sTTARR’s reseachers and users. </h3>
    <div class="smallSpacer"></div> 


    <div class ="row">
      <div class = "col-sm-4" style ="text-align: center;">
        <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray; ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
        <img src = "/images/news1.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px;">
        <div class="smallSpacer"></div>
        <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
      </div>

      <div class = "col-sm-4" style ="text-align: center;">
        <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray; ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
        <img src = "/images/news2.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px;">
        <div class="smallSpacer"></div>
        <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo.  </small>
      </div>

      <div class = "col-sm-4" style ="text-align: center;">
        <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray; ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
        <img src = "/images/news3.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px;">
        <div class="smallSpacer"></div>
        <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
        <div class="smallSpacer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="allStories">
      <hr> 
      <h2 style = "text-align:center;" > All Stories</h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="smallSpacer"></div>


      <div class="row">
        <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
          <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
          <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
        </div>
        <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
         <img src = "/images/news1.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px;">
       </div>
     </div>

     <hr> 

     <div class="row">
      <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
        <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
        <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
      </div>
      <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
       <img src = "/images/news2.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px; ">
     </div>
   </div>

   <hr> 

   <div class="row">
    <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
      <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
      <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
     <img src = "/images/news3.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px; ">
   </div>
 </div> 

 <hr>



 <span id="more">

  <div class="row">
    <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
      <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
      <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
     <img src = "/images/news1.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px;">
   </div>
 </div>

 <hr> 

  <div class="row">
  <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
    <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
    <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo.    </small>
  </div>
  <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
   <img src = "/images/news2.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px; ">
    </div>
 </div>

  <hr>
 
  <div class="row">
   <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
   <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
  <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo.         </small>
 </div>
 <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
 <img src = "/images/news3.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px; ">

  </div> 
 </div>
</span>
 </div>


 <div class="centerButton">
 <button onclick="toggleNewsButton()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
 </div>

  </section>

 <div class="bigSpacer"></div><div class="bigSpacer"></div><div   class="bigSpacer"></div></div><div class="bigSpacer"></div></div><div class="bigSpacer"></div>

 <section id = "#" class="">
  <div class = " content-verticalCentreParent">
    <div class = "content-verticalCentreChild">
  <div class = "mainMargins">

   <div class ="row">
      <div class = "col-sm-4" style ="text-align: left;">
        <h2> Updates </h2>
        <div class="smallSpacer"></div>
        <p> Here is a live twitter update.Here is a live twitter update.Here is a live twitter update.Here is a live twitter update. </p>
      </div>

      <div class = "col-sm-8" style ="text-align: center;">
        
        <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="400" data-height="700" href="https://twitter.com/UHN?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets from UHN</a>       <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

      </div>

    <div class = "bigSpacer"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <div class = "bigSpacer"></div>


  <footer>
    <div class = "mainMargins">
     <div class = "smallSpacer"></div>
     <div class = "line"></div>
     <div class = "row">
    <div class = "footer-column">
      <img src="/images/logo.png" style = "height: 40px">
    </div>
    <div class = "footer-column">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <ul class = "">
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Mission</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Social</li>
            <li>Get in touch</li>
          </ul>
    </div>
    <div class = "footer-column">
      <h3>Title</h3>
          <ul class = "">
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Mission</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Social</li>
            <li>Get in touch</li>
          </ul>
    </div>
    <div class = "footer-column">
      <h3>Title</h3>
          <ul class = "">
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Mission</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Social</li>
            <li>Get in touch</li>
          </ul>
    </div>
    <div class = "footer-column">
      <h3>Title</h3>
          <ul class = "">
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Mission</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Social</li>
            <li>Get in touch</li>
          </ul>
    </div>
    <div class = "footer-column">
      <h3>Title</h3>
          <ul class = "">
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Mission</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Social</li>
            <li>Get in touch</li>
          </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
  </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

EXPECTED: button should show the information in the read more tag.

ACTUAL: button doesn't do anything when you click it.

Comment: That because you're calling to `myFunction()` instead of `toggleNewsButton()`. You can see that error in the console.

Comment: I changed it to this <div class="centerButton">
   <button onclick="toggleNewsButton()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
  </div>, but this does not work either.

Comment: You also have an extra `</div>` above the `centerButton` div.

Comment: I've removed this also, but doesn't work

Comment: In the console, I get this error (index):319 Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleNewsButton is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):319). Although I have defined my news button .. so I'm not sure what this means

Comment: It means your function isn't being called at the right time. Where is your script? If you look, here's a working fiddle, just changing the name of the function on the button: https://jsfiddle.net/aj83xbcy/ - The js is loading in the header.

Comment: Where do you have your JS?

Comment: With the jsfiddle, when you click read less that doesn't work for me. Is that how it is for you as well? Because the button should make the content disappear and then re-appear..

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>` with `<button onclick="toggleNewsButton()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>`

You did put the wrong function

```js
function toggleNewsButton() {
    var readmore = document.getElementById("readmore");
    var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
    var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

      if (readmore.style.display === "none") {
      readmore.style.display = "inline";
      btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
       moreText.style.display = "none";
        } else {
      readmore.style.display = "none";
       btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
       moreText.style.display = "inline";
        }
      }
```

```css
#more {display: none;}

    #myBtn{
 color:black;
 background:#fff;
 border: 1px solid black;
 font-size: 17px;
 padding: 7px 12px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 6px 0;
 margin-right: 12px;

    }

     .centerButton{
  text-align: center;
     }

      #myBtn:hover, #myBtn:active {
  background:black;
  color:white;

    }
```

```html
<section id="#" class="">

    <div class="allStories">
        <hr> 
        <h2 style = "text-align:center;" > All Stories</h2>
        <hr>
        <div class="smallSpacer"></div>


        <div class="row">
          <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
            <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
            <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
          </div>
          <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
           <img src = "/images/news1.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px;">
         </div>
       </div>

       <hr> 

       <div class="row">
        <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
          <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
          <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
        </div>
        <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
         <img src = "/images/news2.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px; ">
       </div>
     </div>

       <hr> 

       <div class="row">
      <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
        <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
        <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
      </div>
      <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
       <img src = "/images/news3.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px; ">
       </div>
       </div> 

      <hr>

      <span id="readmore"></span>

         <span id="more">

          <div class="row">
          <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
            <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
            <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
          </div>
          <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
           <img src = "/images/news1.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px;">
         </div>
       </div>

       <hr> 

       <div class="row">
        <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
          <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
          <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
        </div>
        <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
         <img src = "/images/news2.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px; ">
       </div>
     </div>

     <hr>

     <div class="row">
      <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
        <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
        <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
      </div>
      <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
       <img src = "/images/news3.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px; ">

       </div> 
       </div>
       </span>

       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="centerButton">
      <button onclick="toggleNewsButton()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
      </div>

      </section>
```

Comment: I changed the function to the right one, but when I click the button nothing happens still. It is static.  :(

Comment: That means you have an error with your script, maybe you have an error in the console ?

Comment: In the console, I get this error (index):319 Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleNewsButton is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):319). Although I have defined my news button .. so I'm not sure what this means

Comment: That means you didn't call your script correctly and the function isn't found. Make sure you have imported it with a `<script>`tag

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. This also needed changing:

```
if (readmore.style.display === "none") {
```

to

```
if (moreText.style.display === "none") {
```

```js
function toggleNewsButton() {
  var readmore = document.getElementById("readmore");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (moreText.style.display === "none") {
    readmore.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    readmore.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
#more {
  display: none;
}

#myBtn {
  color: black;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 7px 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 6px 0;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.centerButton {
  text-align: center;
}

#myBtn:hover,
#myBtn:active {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section id="#" class="">

  <div class="allStories">
    <hr>
    <h2 style="text-align:center;"> All Stories</h2>
    <hr>
    <div class="smallSpacer"></div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:left;">
        <p class="#" style="color:lightgray;">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
        <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">
        <img src="/images/news1.jpg" style="height:200px; width:300px;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:left;">
        <p class="#" style="color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
        <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">
        <img src="/images/news2.jpg" style="height:200px; width:300px; ">
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:left;">
        <p class="#" style="color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
        <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">
        <img src="/images/news3.jpg" style="height:200px; width:300px; ">
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <span id="readmore"></span>

    <div id="more">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:left;">
          <p class="#" style="color:lightgray;">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
          <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">
          <img src="/images/news1.jpg" style="height:200px; width:300px;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:left;">
          <p class="#" style="color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
          <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">
          <img src="/images/news2.jpg" style="height:200px; width:300px; ">
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:left;">
          <p class="#" style="color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
          <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">
          <img src="/images/news3.jpg" style="height:200px; width:300px; ">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="centerButton">
    <button onclick="toggleNewsButton()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need the `#readmore`, it's an empty `span` after all. Anyway, I got rid this. Also, when you set `display: none` in the css, the `style.display` will be an empty string, it's working only for inline style (See this in action [here](https://jsbin.com/jukelot/edit?html,css,js,console).

Just follow the changes I did.

```js
function toggleNewsButton() {
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (!moreText.style.display || moreText.style.display === "none") {
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    moreText.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#more {
  display: none;
}

#myBtn {
  color: black;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 7px 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 6px 0;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.centerButton {
  text-align: center;
}

#myBtn:hover,
#myBtn:active {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section id="" class="">

  <div class="allStories">
    <hr>
    <h2 style="text-align:center;"> All Stories</h2>
    <hr>
    <div class="smallSpacer"></div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:left;">
        <p class="#" style="color:lightgray;">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
        <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">
        <img src="/images/news1.jpg" style="height:200px; width:300px;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:left;">
        <p class="#" style="color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
        <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">
        <img src="/images/news2.jpg" style="height:200px; width:300px; ">
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:left;">
        <p class="#" style="color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
        <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">
        <img src="/images/news3.jpg" style="height:200px; width:300px; ">
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <span id="more">

          <div class="row">
          <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
            <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
            <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
          </div>
          <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
           <img src = "/images/news1.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px;">
         </div>
       </div>

       <hr> 

       <div class="row">
        <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
          <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
          <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
        </div>
        <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
         <img src = "/images/news2.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px; ">
       </div>
     </div>

     <hr>

     <div class="row">
      <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
        <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
        <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
      </div>
      <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
       <img src = "/images/news3.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px; ">

       </div> 
       </div>
       </span>
  </div>

  <div class="centerButton">
    <button onclick="toggleNewsButton()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: I did exactly as you did but this did not work for me, thank you anyway.

Comment: What do you mean? You see that it's working in the answer. What is the difference? Can you update your question with your updated code so I could check what's wrong with it?

Comment: I have updated my question with my current code. And I still cannot get the button to work. Hopefully you can help me out, if not I really appreciate your time. Looking to hear back from you..

Comment: When you click on that button, an error shows up in the console, right? `Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleNewsButton is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick` and that's the reason it's not working. Why this error shows up? Because when you use the `onclick` attribute, the function you call to, must be in the `window` context. While in your case, the function's declaration is inside `$(document).ready()` so just move it out side and it will work. https://jsbin.com/higalah/edit?js,output (I removed the irrelevant code.

Comment: @tsharma thoughts?

Comment: I changed my button and got it working a different way but thank you Mosh.

Comment: Ok. Glad to hear :)